# How to simply decode JWT with System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt

Tags: .net, jwt

If you look at https://github.com/jwt-dotnet/jwt there is a simple example of decoding and validating a JWT token with one line of code `JWT.JsonWebToken.Decode(token, secretKey);`.  I would like to use the Microsoft provided JWT library (`System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt`) but I am unable to figure out how to complete this simple task.

Given a JWT token and secret (HS256) how can I decode and validate a JWT like that sample or like [this website](http://jwt.io/)?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to work if your secret is a base 64 encoded byte array.

```
public static void ValidateJwtWithHs256(String encodedJwt, String base64EncodedSecret, String validAudience, String validIssuer)
{
    var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        IssuerSigningToken = new BinarySecretSecurityToken(Base64UrlEncoder.DecodeBytes(base64EncodedSecret)),
        ValidIssuer = validIssuer,
        ValidAudience = validAudience,
    };
    SecurityToken securityToken;
    new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().ValidateToken(encodedJwt, tokenValidationParameters, out securityToken);
}
```

Alternatively, you can tell the validator to not validate certain parts like so:

```
var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
{
    IssuerSigningToken = new BinarySecretSecurityToken(Base64UrlEncoder.DecodeBytes(base64EncodedSecret)),
    ValidateAudience = false,
    ValidateIssuer = false,
};
```

Unfortunately, I still don't know how to work in a secret string that isn't base-64 encoded like http://jwt.io does.